# Google Drive API (REST) - Get download, files views and so on....?? (Is it possible??)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-shared-drive

This is documentation which I'm using - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

Does anyone know the way of getting through Google Drive API, the number of times the file was downloaded, views(ideal views by whom)...

I could not find any way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google drive files are denoted by a [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) this contains all the information that you have access to about the file. Only some of the information you are after is available

> **createdTime**    datetime    The time at which the file was created (RFC 3339 date-time).    writable
>
> **modifiedTime**   datetime    The last time the file was modified by anyone (RFC 3339 date-time).
>   Note that setting modifiedTime will also update modifiedByMeTime for the user.
>
> **lastModifyingUser**  nested object   The last user to modify the file.

You can see who last changed the file but you cant see who has seen the file or any information about how many times it was downloaded.

Comment: Is it any other way, which will allow me to get this kind of information?

Comment: @DalmTo no ways to get matrices from google drive API?

Comment: No that kind of data is not exposed by Google.  I would suspect that they have a download counter but its not something that we can see.

Comment: @DalmTo sad, because if it will be possible to get like download counter, will be awesome ... eh..(

Comment: From a user standpoint it would be nice to be able to see some analytics but I dont think this is information Google wants to share.